# Triplet pairing hard to observe?

Tags: superconductivity, topological-order

I am reading [a review](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1736) on topological superconductivity and Majorana Fermions by Flensberg and Leijnse and at some point they state

> Triplet pairing has been predicted for the ground state of the superconductor $Sr_2RuO_4$, but is very sensitive to disorder and has never been observed experimentally.

Could somebody explain why it is harder to observe triplet pairing as opposed to singlet pairing? And why is the latter more sensitive to disorder?

Comment: First, there is a typo in the last sentence: *triplet* superconductivity is difficult (not to observe but) to realise. The reason is their symmetry. Singlet correlations do not break time-reversal symmetry (they are somehow spin-less). As such, they do not care about impurities which do not break time-reversal symmetry. This is the main reason why superconductivity can survive in alloys, and this statement is called the Anderson theorem (see DuckDuckGo about it). Triplet correlations are sensible to any kind of impurity, even the ones which do not break time-reversal. (...)

Comment: And as such they are more difficult to stabilise in realistic systems. Note that the relation between triplet correlations and topological phase is not yet completely clear : 1) perhaps one needs (induced) gap and not correlations (it's subtle) and 2) it is sometimes clear that topology requires triplet correlation, but the reverse is not yet clear (it's a necessary criterion, not a sufficient one). Finally, note that usually it is predicted that triplet correlations exist alongside the singlet states, at least for systems without inversion center, like Sr2RuO4

Comment: @FraSchelle 1) I guess by saying that "singlet correlations are somehow spin-less" you mean that as you pair up a spin up and a spin down electron, they behave as a spin zero particle? 2) Is there an easy way to understand that impurities do not break time-reversal symmetry? 3) Why are impurities sensitive "even" to non-time-reversal-breaking impurities/interactions?

Comment: 1) Singlet correlations behave as singlet states, and are thus invariant under spin rotation, that what I meant by *spinless*. I should have say *invariant against spin rotation* instead, good point. 2) Impurities may or may not break time-reversal symmetry. If they don't, and if your Hamiltonian also don't break time-reversal symmetry, then switching on the impurities in a perturbative way will not lift any degeneracy, hence you do nothing to your system (except perhaps a global energy shift, which is of no physical meaning). 3) Impurities are not sensitive to the time-reversal symmetry (...)

Comment: (...) breaking. Impurities break or do not break time reversal symmetry. For instance a lattice defect does not usually break time reversal, but a spin defect does. Say differently a scalar term in your Hamiltonian does not break time-reversal invariant (think about a $x^2$ potential), a spin-like term will break time reversal symmetry (think about Zeeman). The correlations are invariant or not with respect to the time-reversal symmetry. Singlet pairing is invariant, triplet pairing is not invariant, under a time-reversal operation.